Formal Definition of Expressibility in Logic and Whether Propositional Logic Can Express Universality
Apparently, you are able to prove that graph reachability (whether a finite path exists from a vertex u to a vertex v in a graph G) cannot be expressed in first-order logic (FOL). This is done by defining "reachability can be expressed in FOL" as "there exists a well-formed formula φ such that φ is true iff the interpretation is exactly this: the universe contains exactly the vertices, and the sole predicate P(x,y) means there is an edge from vertex x to vertex y", then using the compactness theorem to obtain a contradiction. An additional assumption is that φ does not use any other predicates other than P.
In natural language, to prove that there isn't a way to convey some meaning in some language like German, we just say it doesn't exist in German (i.e., there is no formal proof per se). Ergo the fact that there is a proof of inexpressibility of reachability in FOL surprised me, and made me wonder if other expressibility claims can be proven.
The fact that "for all x, P(x)" cannot be expressed in propositional logic (PL) is arguably better known than the inability of FOL to express reachability since it is the first thing students are told to motivate learning FOL. Even though this is intuitive, the above proof reminded me that I have yet to find a proof that PL cannot express universality as a finite formula. I would like to prove it, but in order to prove something, it must be formally defined, like in the proof above. I did notice that in the proof above, the interpretation and formula had to be explicitly defined before we could consider any formula, because defining "FOL expresses reachability" differently can make it true as in this answer. I have never encountered, however, a formal definition of "PL expresses '∀x, P(x)'".
Does expressibility have a unified formal definition, or must it be defined on an instance basis (e.g., "FOL can express topic X" has a different definition from "FOL can express topic y" in that they require different assumptions about any formula that expresses the topic and assumptions about the interpretation)? Is there a formal definition of "PL expresses '∀x, P(x)'"? For other topics, how can one go about formally defining "a language/logic expresses [the topic]"?

What "expressibility" means obviously depends on what one is trying to express and with what. One can have a "unified definition" for expressing a predicate given other predicates, but not of vague idea like "something given something else" either in PL or in FOL. ∀ is not even a predicate and "universality" does not make sense without object variables, which are absent in PL, so it is unclear what is there to be 'proved'.

@Conifold On "it is unclear what is there to be 'proved'", I think that's what I am trying to figure out. In natural language, if there isn't any way to say x (some meaning) in a language, the only way we "prove" it is by just saying it doesn't exist. Ergo the fact that there is a proof of inexpressibility of reachability in FOL surprised me, and made me wonder if other expressibility claims can be proven.

@Conifold As for "∀", you are right that it doesn't really make sense; I think a better way to describe it would be "can PL express [some FOL formula]?". I have edited my question to clarify both points.

This answer has some relevant material.

Before wondering whether an expressibility claim can be proven you should wonder whether the expressibility claim makes sense. "Does PL express ∀xP(x)?" is only half of what is needed for that even informally. Expresses given what? ∀xP(x) is a proposition, so set p := ∀xP(x) and PL will trivially express it. Compare to "does FOL express reachability given the sole predicate P(x,y)?"

The word "topic" is too vague. If you allow "topic" to range over any concept that a human can understand and describe, then you won't have a single formal definition that is applicable to all of them, because they all have different formalizations. That is, they are all "shaped" differently in formal mathematical logic, so a single definition would not be able to capture all of their essences.
We can come up with a few reasonably general definitions, but they have strings attached:

We can reuse the "formula" definition that you show for reachability, by generalizing it to something along the lines of the following: If we have predicates P(x1, x2, ...) and Q(y1, y2, ...), and we have one or more axioms relating P to Q, then we can ask whether there exists a formula φ with free variables z1, z2, ... that only uses P, and is satisfied iff Q(z1, z2, ...) is true in the model (given that the model satisfies those axioms). We can also replace P with a series of predicates, allow more free variables, and so on.

Unfortunately, this only works if we have axioms which completely characterize Q in terms of P. Arguably, that was the question to be asked in the first place, so this is just kicking the can down the road.


If we are able to define something purely in terms of our background logic (often something simple, like "truth"), then we can directly ask whether there is a formula with one free variable which satisfies that definition, but we probably cannot avoid defining the relevant axioms, because the problem is likely to be intractable if we don't know what tools are available to the system in the first place (you can almost always describe an extremely weak system that conveniently happens to have a predicate for exactly the definition we want, but can't do anything useful with it beyond that point, and so we need to rule such systems out). In the case of truth, the answer under PA is no.

We can get away with more complicated definitions, if we allow our background logic to be something reasonably powerful like ZFC. But that requires us to formalize the thing just to ask whether it can be formalized, which is again not very helpful if we want to study whether it can be formalized in ZFC. It is perfectly reasonable to do if we are studying a weaker system like PA, or some non-classical logic where the usual rules don't apply.


In the case of a logical operator like ∀, we need to think of the operator as a means of transforming one formula into another, which means it will be easiest to define if we assume our background logic is ZFC. If ∀ is expressible, there must exist a computable function f that takes a formula φ (or its Gödel number, if you prefer) and a variable x, where φ has free variables x, y1, y2, ..., and x does not appear free in any axiom of the theory, and returns a formula ψ, with free variables y1, y2, ..., such that ψ (informally) is true iff φ is true for all x. But that is not sufficient, because we still have not defined what "for all x" means, so now we need to do that. For each variable x (that satisfies the above requirements), we can define an equivalence relation ~ between models such that, for models M and N, M ~ N iff M is identical to N in every way other than the choice of which object x is bound to. Let [M] represent the equivalence class of the model M under this relation. Then we require that ψ is true in all models in [M] if φ is true in all models in [M], and that ψ is false in all models in [M] if φ is false in any model in [M]. If all of those requirements are satisfied, then the algorithm for computing f is an expression of ∀.

